# VSTS work item revision reporting REST API does not honor startDateTime

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api

I'm running a data warehousing project and getting some very weird response when I call _api/wit/reporting/workItemRevision. Some examples:

`GET _apis/wit/reporting/workItemRevisions?api-version=2.2&amp;types=Bug&amp;startDateTime=2017-03-01T13:18`

Returns revisions from 2017-02-22 but the documentation says that shouldn't be possible.

`GET _apis/wit/reporting/workItemRevisions?api-version=2.2&amp;types=Bug&amp;startDateTime=2017-10-01T00:00`

Returns a record modified on `2017-15-14`. The remainder of the records are from `2017-10-19`. The response does not change with different values for startDateTime, either. `2017-10-01T00:00`, `2017-10-02T00:00` and `2017-10-03T00:00` all return exactly the same data, including the outlier from `2017-05-14`. Considering the number of revisions that go into our project, that seems like it's probably an error.

Answer (score -1):

For `startDateTime` property of [Get a batch of work item revisions](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/reporting-work-item-revisions#get-a-batch-of-work-item-revisions) REST API, it specifies work items revisions which after the `startDateTime`:

> Date/time to use as a starting point for revisions, all revisions will
>   occur after this date/time. Cannot be used in conjunction with
>   'continuationToken' parameter.

In another word, it filter the work item revisions which **`System.ChangedDate`** (not `System.AuthorizedDate`or `System.CreatedDate` etc) are after the `startDateTime` you specified.

Such as if your request is

```
GET https://account.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/reporting/workItemRevisions?api-version=2.2&types=Bug&startDateTime=2017-03-01T13:18
```

It will show the revisions which **`System.ChangedDate`** are after 2017-03-01T13:18.

Comment: This doesn't answer the concern. In both invocations, I am receiving revisions with a `System.ChangedDate` that is _less than_ the provided `startDateTime`. As you quoted from the documentation, this should not be the case.

In addition, our account has tens of thousands of work item revisions created each day so having the calls to the API with consecutive dates should not be returning me the same dataset.

Comment: But for my rest api response, it returns all the revisions which `System.ChangedDate` are after `startDateTime`.Can you show the whole response for a certain REST API request which shows the incorrect date?

Comment: Feel free to email me at neilhuiz(at)microsoft.com if you want to get the dirty details. I think we can agree that 2017-09-12T04:46:01.407Z comes before 2017-10-01T00:00:00Z.

`GET https://account.visualstudio.com/project/_apis/wit/reporting/workItemRevisions?api-version=3.0&types=Bug&startDateTime=2017-10-01T00:00:00Z`

Response:
`{
    "values": [
        {
            "id": 6405728,
            "rev": 115,
            "fields": {

// SNIP

                "System.ChangedDate": "2017-09-12T04:46:01.407Z",
// SNIP
            }
        },
// SNIP`

Comment: @Neil Please report the problem in developer community https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html.

Comment: Done: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/139928/vsts-work-item-revision-reporting-rest-api-does-no.html

Comment: FWIW I'm running into the same issue and have tried different sort of things, albeit, without much success. One of the things that I've tried that has worked for me is setting the includeLatestOnly parameter to true. However, doing so does not return all revisions created after the specified datetime.